# Correct way to test a function

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, integration-testing

Is it okay to call `build_admins_message` in the tests to build expected result that will be used in mock assertion?

Implementation:

```
@slack_messages.on_pattern('(?i)^admins$')
def handle_admins_message(event, body, match):
    team_id = event['team_id']
    user_id = body['user']

    message = build_admins_message(team_id, user_id)
    Slack(team_id).send_message(user_id, **message)
```

Tests:

```
class TestAdminsMessageHandler(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        team = SlackTeam.objects.create(team_id='TEAMID')
        SlackUser.objects.create(team=team, user_id='USERID')

    def tearDown(self):
        SlackUser.objects.all().delete()
        SlackTeam.objects.all().delete()

    @mock.patch('slango.slack.Slack.send_message')
    def test_correct_text(self, send_message_mock):
        event = {
            'team_id': 'TEAMID',
            'event': {
                'text': 'admins',
                'user': 'USERID'
            }
        }

        handle_admins_message(event, event['event'])

        expected_message = build_admins_message('TEAMID', 'USERID')

        send_message_mock.assert_called_with('USERID', **expected_message)
```

Implementation of the `build_admins_message`:

```
def build_admins_message(team_id, user_id):
    user = SlackUser.retrieve(team_id, user_id)
    admins = SlackUser.objects.filter(
        is_bot_admin=True, team__team_id=team_id).order_by(
            'real_name', 'display_name')

    attachments = []
    if user.is_bot_admin:
        attachments.append(build_admin_picker())

    for admin in admins:
        attachments.append(build_admin_item(user, admin))

    attachments.append(build_admin_more())

    return {
        'text': "Here is users with admin rights:",
        'attachments': attachments
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would depend on the role of `build_admins_message` in your program.

Since different parts of the program all need to build the message in the same way, this is probably okay. Consider whether you can make it more explicit that `build_admins_message` is used like this, e.g. with dependency injection. Make sure your helper method has its own test. (I usually see using `patch` as a design smell, but remember that doesn't automatically mean something is wrong!)

If instead `build_admins_message` existed solely as a helper function for `handle_admins_message`, then using it in your test violates encapsulation and ties your test to the implementation too much. In that case, I would just manually write out the expected message in my test.

Comment: I use `build_admins_message` function multiple times throughout my program and I would prefer to manually write out expected message too, but `build_admins_message` returns pretty big dictionary.

Comment: How can I make `build_admins_message` a more explicit dependency?

Comment: I've added implementation to the question

Comment: @DmitryChernyshov Looking at it more, I probably wouldn't bother. Maybe patching out `build_admins_message` as well and asserting that that's called. Maybe if I knew your program and the Slack library better I would have a better idea.